# What's the hearing range of Djungarian hamsters?

Tags: hamsters, hearing

The closest I could find was the [hearing range of mice](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hearing_range&oldid=817287236#Mice), which is is 1-70 kHz.

I'm curious for 2 reasons:

- To avoid possible sources of ultrasound that might startle the pet.
- To try recording their sounds and use [pitch shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_shift) techniques to make them audible to humans.

Comment: it looks like there is no information on the net about this,on the top of the wiki page you have linked to there is a diagram with several animals and i think it is possible to use this to find an estimate of the frequenzy range,if you dont need the exact range.

Comment: Have you considered testing this in reverse - most animals hearing ranges are tuned for hearing each other, and pray/predators. So if you can record over a wide frequency range, then see if you can find anything across those ranges.